# Как объединить JS код в функцию и вызвать её?

Tags: javascript, дата

Здравствуйте, Уважаемые незнакомцы! Нужна ваша помощь в объединении разрозненных кусков кода, в общую функцию, с последующим вызовом её значения. Код показывает сегодняшнюю дату.

Код JS:

```
var m_names = ["Января","Февраля","Марта","Апреля","Мая","Июня","Июля","Августа","Сентября","Октября","Ноября","Декабря"];
var d_names = ["суббота","понедельник","вторник","среда","четверг","пятница","воскресенье"];
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);
var curr_date = myDate.getDate();
var curr_month = myDate.getMonth();
var curr_day  = myDate.getDay();
var dayToday = curr_date+" "+m_names[curr_month]+","+" "+d_names[curr_day];
```

В данный момент, для вывода результата я использую конструкцию `<script>document.write(dayToday);</script>` потому что я весьма криворукий и не имея достаточных знаний, не смог заставить работать конструкцию `document.getElementById`.

Надеюсь, люди не пройдут мимо, не останутся равнодушными и помогут решить проблему. Резюмируя просьбу:
1. Помочь в объединении кода в функцию.
2. Помочь в вызове функции.
3. Пожелать топикстартеру взяться за ум и в дальнейшем помогать людям также, как помогли и ему.

Comment: А вы смотрели функцию `toLocaleString`, может уже всё до вас сделали? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из примера в вопросе, функция `now()` будет возвращать строку текущей даты

```js
function now() {
    month = 'Января,Февраля,Марта,Апреля,Мая,Июня,Июля,Августа,Сентября,Октября,Ноября,Декабря';
    week = 'суббота,понедельник,вторник,среда,четверг,пятница,воскресенье';
    date = new Date();
    return date.getDate() + 7 + ' '
    + month.split(',')[date.getMonth()] + ', '
    + week.split(',')[date.getDay()];
}

document.querySelector('.date').innerHTML = now();
```

```html
<span class='date'></span>
```

Для вызова даты через `toLocaleString`, но я не нашёл как её форматировать

```js
now = new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
});

console.log(now);
```

Вызываем где нужно и что нужно

```js
var now = {
    year: new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {year: 'numeric'}),
    month: new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {month: 'long'}),
    day: new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {day: 'numeric'}),
    weekday: new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {weekday: 'long'}),
    hour: new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {hour: 'numeric'}),
    minute: new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {minute: 'numeric'})
};

console.log(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.weekday, now.hour + ':' + now.minute);
```

Или функция для получения даты, используя конкатенацию строк для формата

```js
function now() {
    date = new Date();
 
    year = date.toLocaleString('ru', {year: 'numeric'});
    month = date.toLocaleString('ru', {month: 'long'});
    day = date.toLocaleString('ru', {day: 'numeric'});
    weekday = date.toLocaleString('ru', {weekday: 'long'});
 
    return year + ' ' + month + ', ' + weekday;
}

console.log(now());
```

Comment: все точно работают - проверил

Comment: Простите, но у меня мало знаний, поэтому возник вопрос:
1. Я сделал вызов Javascript кода из внешнего файла в HEAD разделе кода HTML (условно, javascript расположен в: /settings/js/time.js)
2. Добавил <span class='date'></span> в основной файл HTML.

Должен ли появится контент в HTML файле, в <span class='date'></span>? Если да, то у меня не работает.

Comment: @Doofy, я забыл, что клавиша 'Enter' сразу отправляет комментарий, извините за оплошность. Я дописал комментарий, прошу вас ознакомиться с ним. :)

Comment: @MirsardorTulaganov, span нигде сам не появится, его нужно в body поместить или туда, куда нужно. javascript лучше всего подключать после body, в head ему делать нечего. Сначало html, затем скрипт, иначе он не найдёт элемент

Comment: @Doofy, чудеса! Переместил вызов Javascript в конец <body> и всё заработало. Я чтил как догму, что код javascript должен располагаться в <head>, но это оказывается верно не во всех случаях. Пожалуйста, напишите, почему это работает или направьте меня на тот сайт, где об этом написано!

Comment: @MirsardorTulaganov, А как страничка загружается?) Представим что каждая строка грузится друг за дружкой, сверху вниз и первым делом грузится скрипт и начинает работать, но html элементы ещё не успели загрузиться :(, а скрипт их уже ищет и не находит, выдаёт ошибку. Когда элементы загрузились, скрипт уже выдал ошибку и больше не работает :(

Comment: Теперь всё ясно.

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Функция
function getDate() {
      var m_names = ["Января","Февраля","Марта","Апреля","Мая","Июня","Июля","Августа","Сентября","Октября","Ноября","Декабря"];
    var d_names = ["суббота","понедельник","вторник","среда","четверг","пятница","воскресенье"];
  
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 7);
    var curr_date = myDate.getDate();
    var curr_month = myDate.getMonth();
    var curr_day  = myDate.getDay();

    return curr_date + " " + m_names[curr_month] + ", " + d_names[curr_day];  
}

// вызов функции
console.log(getDate());

// или так
var nowDate = getDate();
console.log('функция вернула: ' + nowDate);
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯